# google dialogflow conditional response does not work

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have two  Entity types (@name and @ surname)  . If the customer can enter these two parameters I will send the flow to another page.
is it possible can I do this with conditional response?

I wrote a simple code like below but It does not work. I get "true" as output even if I don't enter my surname

```
if ($session.params.name! = " ") OR ($session.params.surname != " ")
      'true'
    else
      'false'
    endif
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to write the code using Webhook or in the Customize expression field of Dialogflow CX UI?

Comment: I wrote on  conditional response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this by creating a route with a condition.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#cond

A route may include an intent and/or a condition. The CX UI includes this feature as well as boolean logic to help achieve your desired outcome.
[Example condition using user defined session parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y03dt.png)

Then you can define the fulfillment and transition as needed.

Comment: It is helpful to summarize the important details in your answer with external links being citations as Stackoverflow answers might last longer than links.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are not entering anything, the parameter will resolve as 'null', hence, also not " ". I would do it this way.

```
if $session.params.name! = null OR $session.params.surname != null OR ($session.params.name! = " ") OR ($session.params.surname != " ")
      'true'
    else
      'false'
    endif
```